# Why isn't this code working? (on my iphone 6, chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, google-chrome

This is my [website](http://tmiu.com/test.html). I want to do a waterfall and infinite scroll website, it is work fine on pc, but infinite loading not work on my iPhone 6 Chrome. Why?

And there is my code :

```
    <div id="container">    </div>
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="waterfall-tpl">
{{#result}}
    <div class="item">
        <img src="{{image}}" width="{{width}}" height="{{width}}" />
        <!--<p>{{title}}</p>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <span style="color:gray;text-decoration:line-through;">{{price_standard}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:darkred;">{{price_promo}}</span>-->
    </div>
{{/result}}
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="js/waterfall.js"></script>
<script>
$('#container').waterfall({
    itemCls: 'item',
    colWidth: 222,
    gutterWidth: 15,
    gutterHeight: 25,
    checkImagesLoaded: false,
    minCol: 1,
    maxCol: 6,
    isAnimated: true,
    animationOptions: {
    },
    path: function (page) {
        return 'data/data' + page + '.json';
    }    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ios doesn't run scroll events until you lift your finger and stop scrolling. If you release your finger at the bottom, the results load, but until you do that, the infinite scroll code never runs. There isn't really a way around this unfortunately. Maybe show a message like "release to load more" for ios users?